# How to link pull requests in different Azure DevOps repositories?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-extensions

We have several Repositories in Azure DevOps, some in the same project others in different projects.

I'm trying to find out how pull requests could be linked in some fashion.

I know we could actually put urls in the description, for different pull requests, which I'm guess might be our only option.

However, it would useful to be able to see some status across pull requests in different repositories.

I'm picturing a project which has meant changes in different repos, at the end of the project, we'd want to merge all these pull requests at the same time. So having some means of making it obvious across all pull requests, which pull requests are also required. Obviously I'm not expecting one merge / complete all button.

But there would need to be some obvious link.

Maybe there's an extension which might help, or something obvious I've missed.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caribeiro84.pull-request-manager-hub

Comment: You use "!" to mention a PR in the PR description field.

Comment: Will add the status too? Completed etc ? Can this be done in a task work item too?

Comment: No it didnot add status. It can link to work item too using "!".